# Adding and grouping time into hours to make 60 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I work at a mine, and I have been tasked to account for the time and reasons that Excavators spend in a particular state per hour. We run 3 shifts a day (6 - 14 ; 14 - 22 ; 22 - 6). Each excavator's time should add up to 60 minutes per hour(my minutes Column). For the moment, I am just trying to get one excavator to add up across one shift (Shift 1, "Day Shift"), I will then expand this to include all excavators. I managed to get the 1st hour working (6 - 7). The problem is that there are events that will stretch across multiple hours. So essentially, I am trying to duplicate the data for events that stretch across multiple hours. So if an event stretched across 2 hours for instance (6 - 7 and 7 to 8), the total time of the events must be split into 2 lines, each giving me the fraction of the time spent in that hour.

Note: endtime and starttime are in seconds from the start of shift, and duration is also in seconds.

My current query and output is below. As you can see, I got stuck at hour 2 (7 - 8):

```
declare @date as datetime
set @date = (select max(shiftdate) -1 from hist_exproot) 

select shiftdate
    ,shift
    ,rtrim(eqmt) as eqmt
    ,dateadd(second,start+starttime,shiftdate) as event_start
    ,starttime
    ,dateadd(second,start+endtime,shiftdate) as event_end
    ,endtime

    ,case when endtime >= 3600 and starttime < 3600 then (3600 - starttime)/60
        when endtime >= 3600 and starttime < 3600 and endtime < 7200 then (endtime - 3600)/60
        when endtime >= 7200 and starttime between 3600 and 7200 then (7200 - starttime)/60
     else (endtime - starttime)/60 end as minutes

    ,duration/60 as duration

    ,case when hs.category = 1 then 'Ready'
        when hs.category = 2 then 'Utility'
        when hs.category = 3 then 'Delay'
        when hs.category = 4 then 'Standby'
        when hs.category = 5 then 'Scheduled Down'
        when hs.category = 6 then 'Unscheduled Down'
    else 'ukn' end as category

,case when starttime < 3600 and shift# = 1 then '07'
when starttime < 3600 and endtime > 3600 and endtime < 7200 and shift# = 1 then '08'
when starttime >= 3600 and endtime < 7200 and shift# = 1 then '08'
when starttime between 3600 and 7200 and endtime > 7200 and shift# = 1 then '08'
else 'ukn' end as hour

,rtrim(hr.name) as reason 
from hist_statusevents as hs 
inner join hist_reasontable as hr on 
hr.shiftindex = hs.shiftindex and 
hr.reason = hs.reason
inner join hist_exproot as he on 
he.shiftindex = hs.shiftindex 

where shiftdate = @date
and eqmt = 'EX04'
and hr.name not like 'mmsunk'
and shift# = 1
order by  asc
```

Result:

```
+---------------------+-----------+------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------+------------------+------------------+----------+------+-------------------------+
|      shiftdate      |   shift   | eqmt |     event_start     | starttime |      event_end      | endtime |     minutes      |     duration     | category | hour |         reason          |
+---------------------+-----------+------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------+------------------+------------------+----------+------+-------------------------+
| 2018-08-08 00:00:00 | Day Shift | EX04 | 2018-08-08 06:00:00 |         0 | 2018-08-08 06:20:00 |    1215 |            20.25 |            20.25 | Ready    | 07   | Production              |
| 2018-08-08 00:00:00 | Day Shift | EX04 | 2018-08-08 06:20:00 |      1215 | 2018-08-08 06:27:00 |    1607 | 6.53333333333333 | 6.53333333333333 | Standby  | 07   | SHIFT CHANGE            |
| 2018-08-08 00:00:00 | Day Shift | EX04 | 2018-08-08 06:27:00 |      1607 | 2018-08-08 06:29:00 |    1710 | 1.71666666666667 | 1.71666666666667 | Standby  | 07   | SHIFT CHANGE            |
| 2018-08-08 00:00:00 | Day Shift | EX04 | 2018-08-08 06:29:00 |      1710 | 2018-08-08 07:12:00 |    4298 |             31.5 | 43.1333333333333 | Ready    | 07   | Production              |
| 2018-08-08 00:00:00 | Day Shift | EX04 | 2018-08-08 07:12:00 |      4298 | 2018-08-08 07:15:00 |    4493 |             3.25 |             3.25 | Utility  | 08   | Clean Dig/Work Area     |
| 2018-08-08 00:00:00 | Day Shift | EX04 | 2018-08-08 07:15:00 |      4493 | 2018-08-08 08:23:00 |    8598 | 45.1166666666667 | 68.4166666666667 | Ready    | 08   | Production              |
| 2018-08-08 00:00:00 | Day Shift | EX04 | 2018-08-08 08:23:00 |      8598 | 2018-08-08 08:31:00 |    9036 |              7.3 |              7.3 | Delay    | ukn  | Check Maps/Instructions |
| 2018-08-08 00:00:00 | Day Shift | EX04 | 2018-08-08 08:31:00 |      9036 | 2018-08-08 09:54:00 |   14029 | 83.2166666666667 | 83.2166666666667 | Ready    | ukn  | Production              |
| 2018-08-08 00:00:00 | Day Shift | EX04 | 2018-08-08 09:54:00 |     14029 | 2018-08-08 11:51:00 |   21034 |           116.75 |           116.75 | Utility  | ukn  | Move for Blast          |
| 2018-08-08 00:00:00 | Day Shift | EX04 | 2018-08-08 11:51:00 |     21034 | 2018-08-08 14:00:00 |   28800 | 129.433333333333 | 129.433333333333 | Delay    | ukn  | Blasting                |
+---------------------+-----------+------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------+------------------+------------------+----------+------+-------------------------+
```

Sample data:

Hist_Reasontable:

```
shiftindex  cliID   ddbkey  name    reason  status  delaytime   category    mainttime   altname center  isfromshi#  isfromshi
53258   31172   472666  STRUCTURE-OTHER 420 1   1200    6   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   472886  SUSPENSION  450 1   1200    6   NO  0   0   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   475856  SWING SYSTEM    1900    1   1200    6   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   477616  Scheduled Meeting   5410    3   1200    4   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   484656  Service Equip   6410    4   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   484436  Shift Break 6205    4   1200    3   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   482786  Short Move 10 Mins  5505    4   600 2   NO  1   1   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   478166  Strike  5625    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   474866  TRAMMING SYSTEM 1500    1   1200    6   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   473216  TRANSMISSION    645 1   1200    6   NO  0   0   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   475966  TYRES   2000    1   1200    6   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   476076  TYRES-ROCK EJECTOR  2010    1   1200    6   NO  0   0   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   482676  Talk to Supervisor  5415    4   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   485866  Toilet Stop 6820    4   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   485096  Traffic Delay   6710    4   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   485206  Travel to Fuel Bay  6715    4   1200    2   NO  1   1   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   485536  Travel to Wash Bay  6730    4   1200    2   NO  0   0   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   485426  Travel to Water Stand   6725    4   1200    2   NO  0   0   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   485646  Travel to Work Area 6735    4   1200    2   NO  1   1   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   485316  Travel to maintenance   6720    4   1200    2   NO  0   0   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   1893682 UNDEF   6011    4   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    04. Ready
53258   31172   476186  UNDERCARRIAGE   2100    1   1200    6   NO  0   0   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   479926  WAITING ON SHOVEL   6935    3   1200    4   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   474646  WATER SPRAY SYSTEM  1390    1   1200    6   NO  0   0   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   485976  Waiting for Fuel Bay    6905    4   1200    3   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   477836  Waiting for Operator    5610    3   1200    4   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   486086  Waiting for Pad 6910    4   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   486196  Waiting for Water   6915    4   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   479376  Waiting on Clean Up 6615    3   1200    4   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   479596  Waiting on Equipment    6625    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   479706  Waiting on Supplies 6630    3   1200    4   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   479816  Waiting on Tech Support 6635    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   484766  Watering Equip  6415    4   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   483556  Weight Scale    5920    4   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   482566  Work Area Inspection    5320    4   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   NULL    mmsunk  5127    3   0   4   no  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
53258   31172   474976  ACCIDENT DAMAGE 1605    1   1200    6   NO  0   0   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   472776  AIR CONDITIONING    435 1   1200    6   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   472226  AIR SYSTEM  200 1   1200    6   NO  0   0   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   476956  Accident    5205    3   1200    4   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   484326  Add/Change/reroute Power Cabl   6125    4   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   478386  Available but not Required  5705    3   1200    4   YES 1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   472336  BRAKING 300 1   1200    6   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   482126  Blasting    5105    4   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   472556  CABIN   410 1   1200    6   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   483996  Change Bit  6105    4   1200    2   NO  0   0   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   484106  Change Hammer   6110    4   1200    2   NO  0   0   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   484216  Change Rod  6115    4   1200    2   NO  0   0   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   477726  Changing Operators  5605    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   483666  Check Maps/Instructions 6005    4   1200    3   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   481686  Clean Bed/Bucket    5005    4   600 2   NO  0   0   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   481796  Clean Dig/Work Area 5010    4   1200    2   NO  1   1   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   481906  Cleaning Cab    5015    4   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   482016  Cleaning Equip  5020    4   1200    3   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   483336  Cooling Equipment/Tires/Opera   5910    4   1200    2   NO  0   0   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   480036  Crusher waiting for Trucks  6950    3   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   476626  De_rated Production 110 2   1200    1   NO  0   0   NULL    04. Ready
53258   31172   481136  Dump Not Avail  7135    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   480476  Dust    7105    3   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   473326  ELECTRICAL  700 1   1200    6   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   473436  ELECTRICAL-LIGHTING 820 1   1200    6   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   473546  ELECTRICAL-POWER FAILURE    900 1   1200    6   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   473106  ELECTRICAL-PROPULSION   640 1   1200    6   NO  0   0   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   473656  ELECTRICAL-ZESCO EXTERNAL   950 1   1200    6   NO  0   0   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   473766  ENGINE  1000    1   1200    6   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   473876  ENGINE-COOLING SYSTEM   1010    1   1200    6   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   479266  Emergency Drill 6610    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   477506  Employee Eval   5405    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   482236  Equipment Inspection    5305    4   1200    3   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   486306  Equipment Stuck 6920    4   1200    3   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   484876  Equipment Training  6605    4   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   477066  Evacuation  5210    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   482346  FLRA(Risk Assessment)   5310    4   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   485756  Fatigue 6805    4   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   483446  Filling Water Tank  5915    4   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   480256  Flooding/Rain   7010    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   480366  Fog 7020    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   484546  Fuel Equip  6405    4   1200    3   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   486416  GPS Coverage    6925    4   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   474756  GREASE SYSTEM   1405    1   1200    6   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   477176  Ground Conditions   5215    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   474096  HYDRAULIC   1200    1   1200    6   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   474206  IMPLEMENTS-BLADE    1310    1   1200    6   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   474316  IMPLEMENTS-BUCKET   1325    1   1200    6   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   476296  IMPLEMENTS-GET  2230    1   1200    6   NO  0   0   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   481246  Illegal Miners  7140    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   480146  Lightning   7005    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   483006  Long Move 60 Mins   5515    4   3600    2   NO  1   1   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   475416  MAJOR-SHUTDOWN  1740    1   1200    5   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   474426  MAST    1365    1   1200    6   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   472996  MECHANICAL DRIVE    600 1   1200    6   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   483776  Marking  Holes  6010    4   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   483886  Measure Holes   6015    4   1200    3   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   476736  Mechanically De_Rated   115 2   1200    1   NO  0   0   NULL    04. Ready
53258   31172   482896  Medium Move 30 Mins 5510    4   1800    2   NO  1   1   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   477286  Mine Shut Down  5220    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   483116  Move for Blast  5520    4   1200    2   NO  0   0   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   483226  Move to Pattern 5525    4   1200    2   NO  0   0   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   479486  No Access to Crusher    6620    3   1200    4   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   478496  No Ore Control  5805    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   480586  No Pattern/Round    7110    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   480696  No Support Avail    7115    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   478826  No Support Equipment    5825    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   477946  Not Enough Operators    5615    3   1200    4   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   481466  Not Enough Shovels - Breakdow   7150    3   1200    4   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   481026  Not Enough Shovels - Operator   7130    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   481576  Not Enough Shovels - Relocati   7155    3   1200    4   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   481356  Not Enough Trucks - Breakdown   7145    3   1200    4   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   480806  Not Enough Trucks - Operators   7120    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   475086  OTHER-FIRE SUPRESSION   1620    1   1200    6   NO  0   0   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   473986  OTHER-FUEL TANK 1025    1   1200    6   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   476846  Other Operation 5920    2   1200    2   NO  1   1   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   478606  Other Operations    5810    3   1200    2   NO  1   1   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   480916  Out of Material 7125    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   479046  Parked  6310    3   1200    4   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   477396  Poor Ventilation    5225    3   1200    4   NO  0   0   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   482456  Prestart    5315    4   1200    3   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   476406  Production  100 2   1200    1   NO  1   1   NULL    04. Ready
53258   31172   474536  ROTARY HEAD 1375    1   1200    6   NO  0   0   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   476516  Rehandle    5815    3   1200    2   NO  0   0   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   478936  Restocking  5830    3   1200    2   NO  0   0   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   484986  Restricted Access   6705    4   1200    3   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   478056  Return From Unplanned Mainten   5620    3   1200    4   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   478276  Returned from Planned Mainten   5630    3   1200    4   YES 1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   478716  Rework  5820    3   1200    2   NO  0   0   NULL    03. Effectiveness
53258   31172   475306  SCH-BACKLOG 1735    1   1200    5   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   475526  SCH-INSPECTION  1745    1   1200    5   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   475196  SCH-PREVENTIVE MAINTENANCE  1705    1   1200    5   NO  1   1   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   475636  SCH-TYRE RETORQUE   1750    1   1200    5   NO  0   0   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   479156  SHIFT CHANGE    6315    3   1200    4   NO  1   1   NULL    02. Utilisation
53258   31172   475746  STEERING    1800    1   1200    6   NO  0   0   NULL    01. Availability
53258   31172   472446  STRUCTURE-CHASSIS   400 1   1200    6   NO  0   0   NULL    01. Availability
```

hist_statusevents:

```
shiftindex  cliID   ddbkey  eqmt    unit    operid  starttime   endtime duration    reason  status  category    comment vEvent  reasonlink  stdcomm
53258   31172   1940912 EX04    2   000053  3256    3498    242 100 2   1       0   476406  Other
53258   31172   1941292 EX04    2   000053  3715    8973    5258    100 2   1       1   476406  Other
53258   31172   1941672 EX04    2   000053  9154    9711    557 100 2   1       1   476406  Other
53258   31172   1942052 EX04    2   000053  10047   18001   7954    100 2   1       1   476406  Other
53258   31172   1942432 EX04    2   000053  19227   27286   8059    100 2   1       1   476406  Other
53258   31172   1942622 EX04    2   000053  27286   28800   1514    5410    3   4       1   477616  Other
53258   31172   1941482 EX04    2   000053  8973    9154    181 5010    4   2       1   481796  Other
53258   31172   1941862 EX04    2   000053  9711    10047   336 5505    4   2       1   482786  Other
53258   31172   1941102 EX04    2   000053  3498    3715    217 6005    4   3       1   483666  Other
53258   31172   1942242 EX04    2   000053  18001   19227   1226    6205    4   3       1   484436  Other
53258   31172   1940532 EX04    2   000562  1736    2841    1105    100 2   1       1   476406  Other
53258   31172   1940342 EX04    2   000562  1580    1736    156 6315    3   4       0   479156  Other
53258   31172   1939962 EX04    2   mmsunk  0   742 742 100 2   1       0   476406  Other
53258   31172   1940722 EX04    2   mmsunk  2841    3256    415 100 2   1       0   476406  Other
53258   31172   1940152 EX04    2   mmsunk  742 1580    838 6315    3   4       1   479156  Other
```

Expected result, you will notice that there is a duplication of one line, but in the minutes column, it should only calculate the minutes from the end of the previous hour. This is the one event that stretches across both hours, and in the hour column, it is now 8, indicating the next hour:

```
shiftdate   shift   eqmt    event_start starttime   event_end   endtime minutes duration    category    hour    reason
8/9/2018 0:00   Day Shift   EX04    8/9/2018 6:00   0   8/9/2018 6:18   1102    18.36666667 18.36666667 Ready   7   Production
8/9/2018 0:00   Day Shift   EX04    8/9/2018 6:18   1102    8/9/2018 6:31   1876    12.9    12.9    Standby 7   SHIFT CHANGE
8/9/2018 0:00   Day Shift   EX04    8/9/2018 6:31   1876    8/9/2018 6:40   2381    8.416666667 8.416666667 Standby 7   SHIFT CHANGE
8/9/2018 0:00   Day Shift   EX04    8/9/2018 6:40   2381    8/9/2018 7:26   5185    20.31666667 46.73333333 Ready   7   Production
8/9/2018 0:00   Day Shift   EX04    8/9/2018 6:40   2381    8/9/2018 7:26   5185    26.42   46.73333333 Ready   8   Production
8/9/2018 0:00   Day Shift   EX04    8/9/2018 7:26   5185    8/9/2018 7:49   6520    22.25   22.25   Utility 8   Short Move 10 Mins
8/9/2018 0:00   Day Shift   EX04    8/9/2018 7:49   6520    8/9/2018 8:11   7875    11.33333333 22.58333333 Standby 8   Accident
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is doable, but can you give sample data and expected result?

Comment: I cannot seem to add more than a couple of lines of the sample data here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Never mind, edited my 1st post to include the sample data and expected result.

Comment: Can you provide a script that creates and fills the sample tables?

Comment: Script, like an create/insert query?